# VBA : Object Required

Tags: excel, vba, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
Option Explicit

Private ChBrowser As Selenium.ChromeDriver


Sub LogInToScreener()


Dim FindBy As New Selenium.By
Set ChBrowser = New Selenium.ChromeDriver

Dim ButtonElement As Selenium.WebElement

Dim InputElementCollection As Selenium.WebElements
Dim InputElement As Selenium.WebElement

ChBrowser.Start baseUrl:="https://www.screener.in/login"
ChBrowser.get "/?"

' Username - Element exists?

If Not ChBrowser.IsElementPresent(FindBy.name("username"), 3000) Then

    ChBrowser.Quit
    MsgBox "Could not find Username input field", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub

End If

ChBrowser.FindElementByName("username").SendKeys "iaea290857@gmail.com"
 
' Password - Element exists?

If Not ChBrowser.IsElementPresent(FindBy.name("password"), 3000) Then

    ChBrowser.Quit
    MsgBox "Could not find Password input field", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub

End If

ChBrowser.FindElementByName("password").SendKeys "screener_4102"



 
' =======================
' Sending 'TAB' to Chrome
' =======================


    Application.SendKeys "{TAB}"
    
    
' ==================================================
' Check whether the ACTIVE ELEMENT is LOGIN (button)
' ==================================================

    
    Set ButtonElement = ChBrowser.activeElement
    
    'MsgBox "The active element : " & Element.Text
    
            
' =======================
' Button - Button exists?
' =======================



If Not ChBrowser.IsElementPresent(FindBy.Class("button-primary"), 3000) Then

    ChBrowser.Quit
    MsgBox "Could not find the Login button", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
    
Else

    ButtonElement.Click
    
End If

    Debug.Print ChBrowser.URL
    
If ChBrowser.URL = "https://www.screener.in/dash/" Then

    If ChBrowser.FindElementsByTag("input").Count > 0 Then
    
        ' Prints body
    
        Debug.Print ChBrowser.activeElement.tagName
        
        
        ' ============
        ' Collection :
        ' ============
        
        ' Set InputElementCollection = ChBrowser.FindElementsByTag("input")
        
        ' ========================================
        ' Prints 3 - But 'Index' starts from 0,1,2
        ' ========================================
        
        ' Debug.Print ChBrowser.FindElementsByTag("input").Count
         
         Set InputElement = ChBrowser.FindElementsByTag("input")(1)
```

**Error : Object Required**

**1. How to reference : Input Element' (https://www.screener.in/dash/) ?**
**2. How to Enter a value = "Divis" into the Search Box ?**

```
            ChBrowser.FindElementsByTag("input")(1).Value = "Divis"
    
    End If
    

End If

End Sub
```

**Note : I am able to login using username and password. How to "Enter a Company" (Question 2 : See above) in the Search Box (https://www.screener.in/dash/)**

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1**

I was referencing the **wrong index** of the **InputElement**

Set InputElement = ChBrowser.FindElementsByTag("input")(2)

```
Debug.Print "TagName of the <element> : " & InputElement.tagName
```

**Prints** - 'input' in the **Immediate Window**

**Answer 2**

```
InputElement.sendKeys("Divis")
```

[Click 'Here'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jF4Ji.jpg) to see the **desired result**